# How to access other custom method outside work manager?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on app in which first i have to start the process and then update the value so how to access other methods of  custom method o workmanager thanks

```
     class SmsWorkManager(val context : Context, workerParameters:WorkerParameters) :  CoroutineWorker(context  ,workerParameters) {

                override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
                        println("do some task ")}

fun updateMethod(){
         println("how to access this method")}
```

}

// class Instannce for work maanager

```
       val workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance(this  )
       //             val oneTimeRequest =OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SmsWorkManager::class.java)

        
          workManager.enqueue(oneTimeRequest.build())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `Result` after work completion & you can simply use the `updateMethod()` inside your `doWork() like below:

```kotlin
class SmsWorkManager(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :  
CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        println("do some task ")
        updateMethod()
        return Result.success()
    }


    fun updateMethod(){
        println("how to access this method")
    }
}
```

Also, if you are not doing any IO task then you should use a `Worker` instead of a `CoroutineWorker`.

Comment: bro i want to use it outside the workmanager?
some thing like that smsManagerWorker.updateMetho()
not in workManager itself

Comment: Make a method inside a `companion object {...}` block.

Comment: But wouldn't a companion object on the class be accessed via the class, not the instance, without access to any data within the instance? You could add a companion object to `SmsWorkManager` class then do `SmsWorkManager.updateMethod()`, but it wouldn't be able to access anything from the worker instance used, e.g. if `doWork` updated some private property, you couldn't get the value of that property? I think that's what's asked for - how to access the *actual worker instance* that did the work?